# In MatLab, how to adjust the line width drawn by the function 'gplot'?

Tags: matlab, plot

As the help document of Matlab saying, we can use `gplot` in such a form as

```
gplot(A,Coordinates,LineSpec)
```

But when I try to modify the `linewidth` of the line and use a code like

```
gplot(A,Coordinates,'linewidth',2)
```

an error occurred and the error information saying that `Error using gplot:
Too many input arguments.`

I was wondering if their is anything wrong with my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on the answer of PearsonArtPhoto, the lines can be modified if they are explicitly found using `findall(gcf,'type','line')`.

This is a working example:

```
k = 1:30;
[B,XY] = bucky;
gplot(B(k,k),XY(k,:),'-*')
set(findall(gcf,'type','line'),'LineWidth',5)
axis square
```

which produces the following figure
[image: Gplot with modified LineWidth.]

Answer (score 2):

You could always do it manually. Try doing this right after plotting your figure.

```
set(gco,'LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: Thx, Pearson. But I prefer a real time method to modify the line width, because the function of gplot is used combining with other plot functions on the same figure. I just want to modify the line width plotted by gplot, whereas the lines plotted by other function will keep their own width.

Comment: This will only update the width of the last line. Gco=get current object.

Comment: I tried to use the following code, but it still cannot work. 'figure(3)
gplot(G,x)
set(gco,'LineWidth',3)'