# Matlab, gplot custom linewidth for some lines, but not all

Tags: matlab

In the past, there has been asked a question about customizing the linewidth in gplot (see [In MatLab, how to adjust the line width drawn by the function 'gplot'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777821/in-matlab-how-to-adjust-the-line-width-drawn-by-the-function-gplot)). I am dealing with a slightly more complicated version, which prevents me from using the solution given there. Therefore, I would like to ask how to do the following: I would like to adapt the line width of some of the calls of gplot, and not of others. I am namely calling gplot several times and using hold on to plot them in one figure. I am trying to draw a graph, with multiple types of edges (A and A2). And k paths in it. I am currently using the following code:

```
figure
hold on
gplot(A,coor,'k*:')
gplot(A2,coor,'k-')
plot(coor(T,1),coor(T,2),'k.','MarkerSize',20)
plot(coor(T,1),coor(T,2),'bo','MarkerSize',20)
% a line where I define my own colors (not shown, since not relevant)
set(gca,'ColorOrder',colors)
hold all
for i=1:k
    gplot(Path,coor)
end
hold off
```

But I would like to draw the paths with a larger line width, while keeping the A and A2 at the standard line width 1.

Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the children of the axis before and after adding the extra lines, and only set the new ones to have a larger linewidth:

```
figure
hold on
gplot(A,coor,'k*:')
gplot(A2,coor,'k-')
plot(coor(T,1),coor(T,2),'k.','MarkerSize',20)
plot(coor(T,1),coor(T,2),'bo','MarkerSize',20)
ChildrenBefore=get(gca,'children');
% a line where I define my own colors (not shown, since not relevant)
set(gca,'ColorOrder',colors)
hold all
for i=1:k
    gplot(Path,coor)
end
hold off
ChildrenAfter=get(gca,'children');
NewChildren=setdiff(ChildrenAfter,ChildrenBefore);
set(intersect(findall(gcf,'type','line'),NewChildren),'LineWidth',5)
```

Comment: @dro, please mark this question as an answer, that's how SO works!